# Can I distribute a distributed availability group?

Tags: availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

Server1 and Server2 make up a NEW availability group: AGServer.

DMZ1 and DMZ2 already make up an existing availability group: AGDMZ.

Currently DMZ1 & DMZ2 are part of a Distributed Availability Group with a reporting server: DAGRPT.

I need to set up replication from AGServer to AGDMZ, and then across to DAGRPT.

So, can I distribute a distributed availability group?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed to do was to replicate the data from one AG to another and then Distribute that. Excellent article outlining the steps to take and on which  server to run the code.
https://www.techbrothersit.com/2015/07/how-to-setup-replication-with-alwayson.html